# Ajax not working once adding if statement?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I feel like I'm making a really obvious mistake. Please bear with me, I just started learning jquery and ajax.

Basically, I think something's wrong with my if statement. Everything else is working properly: ajax was called successfully and the value of the data returned was "no". However, as soon as I put in the if statement, all the commands in the if statement fail to run. What am I doing wrong?

Html:

```
<button class='clicky'>Click Me</button>

<section class='modal'>
    <p>Some text</p>
</section>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".clicky").on('click', function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "indexFunct.php", 
                    type: "POST", 
                    success: function(data){
                        //alert with data if successfully called ajax; showed data = "no" 
                        //alert(data); 

                        //does not alert with data if code for alert is inside if statement 
                        if(data==='no')
                        {
                        alert(data);
                        }
                    }, 
                    error: function(er){
                        alert('error'); 
                    }
                })
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

test.php:

```
<?php echo "no"; ?>
```

Comment: Try to remove `?>` in your php file.

Comment: hmmm maybe there are some spaces after `?>` and they are returned as a response ; so the equality `data=='no'` fails. Try removing all spaces and newlines after `?>`.

Comment: Does it work if you do use the `==` instead of `===` like `if(data == 'no')`

Comment: @Pierre changed your mind, lol))))

Comment: @u_mulder : yes, thought later about trailing spaces, and so did you some seconds before

Comment: Your ajax request points to `indexFunct.php` but you have shown code from `test.php` - what does `indexFunct.php` do that `test.php` does not?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious reason why your `if(data==='no')` does not work is that `data` is **not** `"no"`. It can be for example `"no "` (with ending space) or `"no\n"`, where `\n` is **newline**.

Why you get space or newline in the output? Because you have them in your php-file.

What to do? Manually remove them.

If your php file is consist only of php-code, you can omit closing `?>` so as not to output anything after last `echo`, your test.php becomes:

```
<?php echo "no";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

> Put a `console.log(data)` and validate the response.

Your data has a space "`<?php echo "no"; ?>` "<--- here before quotes